# Change the image source based on binded boolean

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have the Contact class:

```
public class Contact
{
    public Contact(Contact contact)
    {
        this.Username = contact.Username;
        this.GUID = contact.GUID;
        this.Msg = contact.Msg;
        this.Ring = contact.Ring;
    }

    public string Username { get; set; }
    public Guid GUID { get; set; }
    public bool Msg { get; set; }
    public bool Ring { get; set; }
}
```

This is the xaml:

```
        <ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Name="ContactsListView" 
                      IsItemClickEnabled="True" 
                      ItemsSource="{x:Bind m_Client.Contacts}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Contact">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Username}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    // HERE SHOULD BE THE <Image> THAT SHOULD BE BOUND TO THE Msg PROPERTY
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

What I need to accomplish is that when the Msg boolean is true, the image source to be one image, and when the Msg boolean is false the image source to change to the second image.

**EDIT:**
I created this class:

```
namespace ContactsListBinding.Models
{
    public class MyImageConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            return (bool)value ? new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/true.png")) : new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/false.png"));
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the XAML:

```
<Page
    x:Class="ContactsListBinding.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:ContactsListBinding"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:data="using:ContactsListBinding.Models"
    xmlns:namespace="ContactsListBinding.Models">

    <Page.Resources>
        <data:MyImageConverter x:Key="MyImageConverter" />
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Name="AddContactButton" Content="Add Contact" Click="AddContactButton_Click" />
        <ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Name="ContactsListView" 
                          IsItemClickEnabled="True" 
                          ItemsSource="{x:Bind m_Client.Contacts}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Contact">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Username}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        <Image Source="{x:Bind Msg, Converter={StaticResources MyImageConverter}}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: creating Converter implementing IValueConverter that will return proper image source based on input (string Msg) and binding ImageSource={x:Bind Msg, Converter=YourMsgToImageSourceConverter} should do the work

Comment: Would you mind giving me an example of how should I do this?

Comment: Change your resource to data:MyImageConverter and add new BitmapImage as I did in my answer below. Where are your two images, in Assets folder or somewhere else?

Comment: I changed the resource to `<data:MyImageConverter x:Key="MyImageConverter" />` and there is the following error: The name MyImageConverter does not exist in the namespace "using:ContactsListBinding.Models"

Comment: And are you sure you have the converter in the right folder? If it would right, IntelliSense would automatically offer you this class.

Comment: Yes, the class is in the Models folder

Comment: And if you type "<data:" to your resource and press CTRL + Space, does IntelliSense see this class and show it to you?

Comment: Yes, it shows <data:MyImageConverter but there error remains The name MyImageConverter does not exist in the namespace "using:ContactsListBinding.Models"

Comment: I looked at your class and 1) It's not public 2) It doesn't implement IValueConverter interface. It's just here or is this problem also in your solution?

Comment: I have just updated the question with my current class implementation ant the XAML

Comment: I don't have any idea, now it looks right. The error is still the same?

Comment: Yes, now it works. It seems event though the IntelliSense says there is an error, the application builds just fine. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a converter:

```
public class MyImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
   {
      return (bool)value ? new BitmapImage(new Uri("trueImagePath")) : new BitmapImage(new Uri("falseImagePath"));
   }

   public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
   {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
   }
}
```

You also need to add resource to your page:

```
<Page.Resources>
   <namespace:MyImageConverter x:Key="MyImageConverter" />
</Page.Resources>
```

And than add image control like this:

```
<Image Source="{x:Bind Msg, Converter="{StaticResources MyImageConverter}"}" />
```

Comment: I did this `<Page.Resources>
        <ContactsListBinding.Models:Converter x:Key="Converter" />
    </Page.Resources>` and it says Converter is not supported in Windows Universal Project.

Comment: I just maybe use some internal name, try to rename for ex. to MyImageConverter. **EDIT** And also namespace must be added in Page element like xmlns:namespace="yourNamespace" or if it's the same namespace as your View, use local:MyImageConverter

Comment: Stefan, I hope you put correct image path instead - `trueImagePath` and `falseImagePath`

Comment: Of course I did :) Check my updated question, there is the new code.

Answer (score 2):

Use Trigger, code is short

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Contact">
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
               <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Username}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
               <Image Source="false.png">
                    <Image.Triggers>
                         <DataTrigger TargetType="Image" Binding="{x:Bind Msg}" Value="True">
                              <Setter Property="Source" Value="true.png" />
                          </DataTrigger>
                     </Image.Triggers>
               </Image>
         </StackPanel>
   </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: There's no dataTrigger in uwp

Comment: @Rafi Henig, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44133129/datatriggers-do-not-work-when-compiling-uwp-application-as-release)

Answer (score 1):

You should create your custom converter which implements `IValueConverter` interface

```
public class MsgToImagePathCovnerter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        var imagePath = "ms-appx:///Assets/1.jpg";
        var msg = (bool)value;
        if (msg)
        {
            imagePath = "ms-appx:///Assets/2.jpg";
        }

        return imagePath;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

declare in XAML:

```
<local:MsgToImagePathCovnerter x:Key="MsgToImagePathCovnerter"/>
```

and use in your `DataTemplate`:

```
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Contact">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Username}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                <Image Source="{x:Bind Msg, Converter={StaticResource MsgToImagePathCovnerter}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Where exactly should I put this line: `<local:MsgToImagePathCovnerter x:Key="MsgToImagePathCovnerter"/>`?

Comment: fore example, <Page.Resources> </Page.Resources>