# DataTriggers do not work when compiling UWP application as RELEASE

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp, xamarin.forms

I have a `UWP` application build using `Xamarin.Forms` I have a simple `DataTrigger` on a `Grid` like so:

```
<Grid.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger TargetType="Grid" Binding="{Binding Selected}" Value="True">
         <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource SelectedListItemColour}"/>
    </DataTrigger>
    <DataTrigger TargetType="Grid" Binding="{Binding Selected}" Value="False">
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource ContentGridColour}"/>
    </DataTrigger>
</Grid.Triggers>
```

This works absolutely fine when building as **DEBUG**.

But when I build against **RELEASE** using the **.Net Native Toolchain** (required for Windows Store apps) the datatrigger stops working, almost as if it doesn't exist at all, no error, just nothing.

Has anyone seen this before or managed to solve it?

**Edit:**

I have added a sample application [here](http://www.filedropper.com/showdownload.php/datatriggertest).
Steps to replicate:

1. Run application in UWP using Debug - see it works fine
2. Run application in UWP using Release - doesnt work

Comment: I have tried to  reproduce your issue by `<DataTrigger TargetType="StackLayout" Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference MyLanel },Path=Text.Length }" Value="0">` . It works fine when building as RELEASE . Could you show more detail about your `control` that you want to monitor?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I have added a sample application to the question with some steps to reproduce. See Sample. I don't know whether this is a Microsoft problem or a Xamarin one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is a `Xamarin.Forms` issue outlined [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/windows/installation/universal/#Troubleshooting):

> "Target Invocation Exception" when using "Compile with .NET Native
>   tool chain" If your UWP app is referencing multiple assemblies (for
>   example third party control libraries, or your application itself is
>   split into multiple PCLs), Xamarin.Forms may be unable to load objects
>   from those assemblies (such as custom renderers).
>
> This might occur when using the Compile with .NET Native tool chain
>   which is an option for UWP apps in the Properties > Build > General
>   window for the project.
>
> You can fix this by using a UWP-specific overload of the Forms.Init
>   call in App.xaml.cs as shown in the code below (you should replace
>   ClassInOtherAssembly with an actual class your code references):

This meant that I had to do:

```
Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e, new[] { typeof(Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Extensions).GetTypeInfo().Assembly });
```

To get `DataTriggers` to work

Notice how Xamarin have not documented this. For their own library!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is something weird in your code project. I can only reproduce your issue base on the project you provided. I have created a new project but failed to reproduced it. You can refer to  the following is code.

**HomePage.xaml**

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:HomePageViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <StackLayout>
        <StackLayout.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger TargetType="StackLayout" Binding="{Binding  IsSelected }" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Green"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger TargetType="StackLayout" Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Red"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </StackLayout.Triggers>
        <Button x:Name="MyBtn" Command="{Binding Trigger}" Text="ClickMe" />
    </StackLayout>
```

**HomePageViewModel.cs**

```
 public class HomePageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
 {
     public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
     public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string PropertyName = null)
     {
         this.PropertyChanged(this,new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
     }

     private bool _isSelected;
     public bool IsSelected
     {
         get { return _isSelected; }
         set
         {
             _isSelected = value;
             OnPropertyChanged();
         }
     }

     private Command _trigger;
     public Command Trigger
     {
         get
         {
             return _trigger
                 ?? (_trigger = new Command(
                 () =>
                 {
                     IsSelected = !IsSelected;
                 }));
         }
     }
 }
```

I have uploaded the [code sample](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/DataTriggerTest.git) to github. Please note that I used the `INotifyPropertyChanged` instead of the Mvvnlight nuget package.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I managed to get to the bottom of the issue with the help of some people on the Xamarin Forum. Its a Xamarin.Forms related issue and I have posted the answer for others