# If else statement with image in xaml vb

Tags: windows, vb.net, xaml, vpn

Previously I have a rectangle button with has connect and disconnect button. When I click connect button, the program can run the connection() function and the text change to "disconnect". When I click "disconnect" button, the program can end the connection() function and the text change to "connect" again.

In xaml:

```
<Label x:Name="lb_con" Cursor="Hand" Content="Connect" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="White" Margin="0,60,0,0" FontWeight="Bold"/>
```

In xaml.vb, I have connection() function like this:

```
Private Sub connection()
    
    If tb_server.Text = String.Empty Or tb_username.Text = String.Empty Or tb_psdd.Text = String.Empty Then
        MsgBox("All fields are required", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Empty Fields")
        Exit Sub

    End If
    intDisconnected = False
    
    If lb_con.Content = "Connect" Then        
        If (CheckInternetConnection() = True) Then
            Try
                .
                .
                .
                rashandler = rasdialer.DialAsync()
                lb_con.Content = "Disconnect"

            Catch exc As Exception
                MsgBox(exc.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Connection Error")

            End Try
        Else
            MsgBox("Either your internet Or server (http: //www.google.com) used to check internet connectivity is down.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Connection Error")
        End If

    ElseIf lb_con.Content = "Disconnect" Then
        intDisconnected = True

            If (rasdialer.IsBusy) Then
                rasdialer.DialAsyncCancel() 
            Else
                Dim con As RasConnection = RasConnection.GetActiveConnectionByHandle(rashandler) 

                If (con IsNot Nothing) Then
                    con.HangUp()
                End If

            End If
        lb_con.Content = "Connect"

    End If

End Sub



Private Sub lb_con_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseButtonEventArgs) Handles lb_con.MouseDown
    If e.LeftButton = MouseButtonState.Pressed Then
        connection()
    End If
End Sub
```

Now, I want to change the "lb_con" with my image, connect with power_on.png and disconnect with power_off.png. But, after I change to those images, when I run the project, the images doesn't do anything after I click the image.

This is my xaml code after I change to image:

```
<Image x:Name="lb_con" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,74,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="Resources/power-on.png" Cursor="Hand"/>
```

And this is my xaml.vb code:

```
Private Sub connection()
    
    If tb_server.Text = String.Empty Or tb_username.Text = String.Empty Or tb_psdd.Text = String.Empty Then
        MsgBox("All fields are required", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Empty Fields")
        Exit Sub

    End If
    intDisconnected = False
    
    If Object.ReferenceEquals(lb_con.Source, My.Resources.power_on) Then        
        If (CheckInternetConnection() = True) Then
            Try
                .
                .
                .
                rashandler = rasdialer.DialAsync()
                lb_con.Source = New BitmapImage(New Uri("Resources/power-off.png", UriKind.Absolute))

            Catch exc As Exception
                MsgBox(exc.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Connection Error")

            End Try
        Else
            MsgBox("Either your internet Or server (http: //www.google.com) used to check internet connectivity is down.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Connection Error")
        End If

    ElseIf Object.ReferenceEquals(lb_con.Source, My.Resources.power_off) Then
        intDisconnected = True

            If (rasdialer.IsBusy) Then
                rasdialer.DialAsyncCancel() 
            Else
                Dim con As RasConnection = RasConnection.GetActiveConnectionByHandle(rashandler) 

                If (con IsNot Nothing) Then
                    con.HangUp()
                End If

            End If
        lb_con.Source = New BitmapImage(New Uri("Resources/power-on.png", UriKind.Absolute))

    End If

End Sub


Private Sub lb_con_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseButtonEventArgs) Handles lb_con.MouseDown
    If e.LeftButton = MouseButtonState.Pressed Then
        connection()
    End If
End Sub
```

Is there anything wrong with my code? Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: you need to look into MVVM and bind the source to property and add notify property change for xaml to reload and update the window.

Answer (score 0):

One example maybe would be do something style based, binding to a boolean property:

```xml
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Contact"> 
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
               <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Username}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
               <Image Source="false.png">
                    <Image.Triggers>
                         <DataTrigger TargetType="Image" Binding="{x:Bind Msg}" Value="True">
                              <Setter Property="Source" Value="true.png" />
                          </DataTrigger>
                     </Image.Triggers>
               </Image>
         </StackPanel>
   </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65492475/14106028